# Code::Blocks 13.12 Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s) )

Tags: c++, xterm, code-blocks

I installed CodeBlocks in ubuntu and try with a hello world c++ program with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and when I tried to compile, I have got:

```
Checking for existence: /home/sara/Pulpit/kurs c/test1/bin/Debug/test1
Executing: xterm -T test1 -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /home/sara/Pulpit/kurs\ c/test1/bin/Debug/test1  (in /home/sara/Pulpit/kurs c/test1/.)
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have g++ and xterm installed. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ xterm
```

Now in *Settings* -> *Compiler* -> *Toolchain executables* tab -> *C++ compiler* there should be `g++` If `g++` isn't there, then closing and reopening Code::Blocks should put it there after where it says *C++ compiler:*.

Before you run your code, which should run successfully, select *File* -> *New* -> *Project* -> *Console application* -> *C++* and continue until the end of the wizard. Then select *Build* -> *Build* to build it and click the green triangle run icon to run the program.

A new XTerm window will open with the following results:

```
Hello world! 

Process returned 0 (0x0)  execution time : 0.002 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Comment: I intstal g++, but that's not working. Program show me the same error message.

Comment: The file compiles but doesn't start.

Comment: You can also run the program from the Code::Blocks menu  by selecting *Build* -> *Run* and it should show the results in a new XTerm window if xterm is installed. If xterm is not installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install xterm`.

Comment: One last thing. The `-1` in the error message `Process terminated with status -1` is a code that means the compile process failed for some reason (e.g. g++ was not installed because there is nothing wrong with the code). No XTerm window opened when running the program  suggested that xterm was not installed either.